# JSON object to array by key

Tags: arrays, object

How do I extract/collect the values for a given key from JSON into an array?

Specifically I want to extract the `name` values from:

```
{
  data: [
    { id: 0, name: 'one' },
    { id: 1, name: 'two' },
    { id: 2, name: 'three'}
  ]
}
```

To get:

```
['one','two','three']
```

Comment: Try: `data.map(person => person.name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return/pick only the name from the objects:

```js
const obj = { data: [{ id: 0, name: 'one' }, { id: 1, name: 'two' }, { id: 2, name: 'three' }] }

console.log(obj.data.map(x => x.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve above by using [JSONPath](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/), Try below:

```
 $.data[:].name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
let obj = {
  data: [
    { id: 0, name: 'one' },
    { id: 1, name: 'two' },
    { id: 2, name: 'three'}
  ]
}

let names = obj.data.map { ( $0.name )} // get names
```